How to set options for an embedded audio file in Powerpoint?
I am going to embed an audio file to pptx file and then set "Start Automatically" and "Hide During Show" option with Python code, which is in Power Point Audio Option Setting.
But I have no way.
I used "python-pptx".
This is code snippet for the logic:
prs = Presentation(pptx_path)
while len(prs.slides) <= slide_index:
    prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[5])  
    slide = prs.slides[slide_index]
    left = top = Inches(1) width = height = Inches(1)
    audio_shape = slide.shapes.add_movie(     
        audio_path,
        left, top, width, height,
        mime_type='audio/mpeg', poster_frame_image=None
    )


How can I set the options with Python?
